# Implementing an audio button for an online learning course

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an online learning course and I want this button:

https://lwfiles.mycourse.app/diqual-training-public/4bed6d14166fb6c6ae774de7077539ab.png?client_id=5eaee65ac7f0fc16f233921d&amp

to be able to be clicked and then an audio file gets played and then when you click the button it pauses again.

I want to do this all with html5 but i can only get it to play when clicked.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

SHORT ANSWER:

You probably can't, use JS, learn JS with freecodecamp.org (if you learned HTML and CSS already)

It's a course website, it probably will need some JS and PHP etc

Use the HTML5 Audio Tag:

```
 <audio controls>
  <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Working:
https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio

You need the file to play it.

I also found a easy way to do it:

```
<audio src="demo.mp3" controls></audio> 
<!-- Seems to not work... use the other one found in the repl below -->
```

You need `<!DOCTYPE html>`

This is the closest I can get, you need to use JS...

https://repl.it/@DarmiyaevDev/Audio#index.html

This is all pure HTML5

Sorry I think you need JS to use an image onclick audio.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <image src="audio.png" width="50vh" height="50vh"></image>
     <audio controls>
  <source src="8 Bit FX.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
  </body>
</html>
```